# Is there a way to install a specific submodule of a package?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm working on a serverless project using `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` using AWS Lambda.

AWS requires that all dependencies get uploaded with the project during deploy, is there a way to install only the files needed to use a specific classifier so I can save some bandwidth?

Comment: What if those submodules require some files from other submodules of same package or maybe other dependent libraries?

Comment: I believe this happens, but I also know lots of what is in that package is unnecessary

Comment: Yes  I understand that. Because the current structure of scikit will have base classes in some other submodules, which can be seen in the imports on the top of MLPClassifier file](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py). You need all of them in addition to numpy and scipy libraries.

Comment: Wow, nice. I'll try to bundle it by hand then! Thanks!